# Use an app as a service and a commandLine tool

Tags: c#, windows

I want to use my simple console app as a service with `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` and as a commandline tool with `McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils` parsing. What is the right way to do this? Currently I'm just checking for args length.

```
   [Option("-v|--Verbose", CommandOptionType.SingleValue)]
    public bool Verbose { get; }

    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello there. Executing as a console app or a service.");

            // execute long running process logic. But eliminate duplication of execution.
            // start service as below / or, for: i < 100 => sleep(10sec); 

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            CommandLineApplication.Execute<Program>(args);
        }
        
    } 

 
    public void OnExecute()
    {
        //Do I check options and start execution of service logic here or from main method?
        Console.WriteLine("Verbose = " + Verbose);
    }


    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            }) ;
    }
```

Comment: "as a service" you mean as a Windows Service? Where's your code that uses Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting to build the host and execute it? How do you want to detect if you should run as a Windows Service or not?

Comment: Right, as a windows service. I have added the code of hostbuilder part. I am not sure about what is a good way to detect if I should run as a Windows Service or a commandLine Tool.

Comment: "Right" way is subjective. You already have the infrastructure to parse command line arguments, couldn't you just add another flag to run in Windows Service mode?

Comment: I think its good if its running as service, eg auto start, I do not create CommandLineApp with parsing.